# C# (MediaFrameReader API) SoftwareBitmap doesn't show

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp

I followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader) to implement MediaFrameReader API in order to process video captured by camera. The problem is I don't know why the bitmap doesn't show up in XAML, I can't save it to jpeg either (bitmap is not empty).  I did convert the bitmap to proper format for XAML:

Here's my code to show the frame in XAML control (no error):

```
public void ShowSoftwareBitmap(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap, SoftwareBitmap backBuffer, Image imageElement, bool taskRunning)
    {
        try
        {
            //check if softwareBitmap is in proper format (Bgra8 and premultiplied alpha) to display to XAML Image control 
            if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
                softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode != BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied)
            {
                softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
            }

            if(softwareBitmap != null)
            {
                softwareBitmap = Interlocked.Exchange(ref backBuffer, softwareBitmap);
                softwareBitmap?.Dispose();
                var task = imageElement.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                async () =>
                {
                    if (taskRunning)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    taskRunning = true;

                    SoftwareBitmap latestBitmap;
                    while ((latestBitmap = Interlocked.Exchange(ref backBuffer, null)) != null)
                    {
                        SaveSoftwareBitmapToJpg(latestBitmap, 2);
                        var imageSource = (SoftwareBitmapSource)imageElement.Source;
                        await imageSource.SetBitmapAsync(latestBitmap);
                        latestBitmap.Dispose();
                    }
                    taskRunning = false;
                }
                );
            }

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Backbuffer is empty." + e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Here's my code to save it to jpeg (error unsupported bitmap format):

```
public async void SaveSoftwareBitmapToJpg(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap, int _frameIndex)
    {
        StorageFolder captureFolder = await FileAccess();
        StorageFile outputFile = await captureFolder.CreateFileAsync($"capture{_frameIndex}.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)) 
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 300;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 300;
            encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated = true;
            try
            {
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                switch (e.HResult)
                {
                    case unchecked((int)0x88982F81): //WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDOPERATION
                                                     // If the encoder does not support writing a thumbnail, then try again
                                                     // but disable thumbnail generation.
                        encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw e;
                }
            }
            //catch error generating thumbnail
            if (encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated == false)
            {
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I changed my code:

In `ShowSoftwareBitmap()`, I used the same boolean `taskRunning` in other methods so it was changed crazily in run time. Just create another boolean to solve the problem.

In save `SaveSoftwareBitmapToJpg()`, the bitmap wasn't properly converted, it has to be Rgba8 or Rgba16 to print to JPEG, so the same conversion used for `ShowSoftwareBitmap()` wouldn't work. Use this instead:

```
try
{
    if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16)
       {
          result = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16);
       }
    else
       {
          result = SoftwareBitmap.Copy(softwareBitmap);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested with your code snippet, if you invoking the above methods correctly with a correct `SoftwareBitmap` object, the above methods could work well. Simply for example:

```
 <Image x:Name="imgshow" ></Image>
 imgshow.Source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
 SoftwareBitmap _backBuffer = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 300, 400);
 ShowSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap, _backBuffer, imgshow, false);
```

So that issue may be not happened with the methods above. This could help you narrow the issue, you could check if something wrong when getting the `SoftwareBitmap` object. I saw you may copy code from `ProcessFrame` method which is in [`FrameRenderer`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraFrames/cs/FrameRenderer.cs) class of the official sample. The official sample get the `SoftwareBitmap` by converting `VideoMediaFrame`, check if anything wrong when you converting.

Also please debug your code to see if `taskRunning` is `false` that your code do run into setting image source steps.

Comment: I still can't get the output image shown on XAML. I tried every other pixel and alpha format.